# Wrong instance passed in Laravel DB post request

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

So I am working on a page in Laravel that generates invite codes upon email submission. I have run into this issue, every time when I enter my email into the form, it is supposed to generate an invite code an input it into my DB then redirect me. Instead I get this error code:

```
Argument 1 passed to myapp\Repositories\Invite\EloquentInviteRepository::__construct() 
must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, instance of 
Illuminate\Foundation\Application given, called in /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php 
on line 4259 and defined
```

This is my **EloquentInviteRepository.php** file, apparently line 21 is the line in error:

```
<?php namespace myapp\Repositories\Invite;

use myapp\Repositories\Crudable;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
use myapp\Repositories\Repository;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use myapp\Repositories\AbstractRepository;

class EloquentInviteRepository extends AbstractRepository implements Repository, Crudable, InviteRepository {

/**
* @var Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
*/
protected $model;

/**
* Construct
*
* @param Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $user
*/
public function __construct(Model $model)
{
 parent::__construct(new MessageBag);

 $this->model = $model;
}

/**
* Find a valid invite by a code
*
* @param string $code
* @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
*/
public function getValidInviteByCode($code)
{
return $this->model->where('code', '=', $code)
                   ->where('claimed_at', '=', null)
                   ->first();
}

/**
* Create
*
* @param array $data
* @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
*/
 public function create(array $data)
{
   $data['code'] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));

   return $this->model->create($data);
}

/**
* Update
*
* @param array $data
* @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
*/
public function update(array $data){}

/**
* Delete
*
* @param int $id
* @return boolean
*/
 public function delete($id){}

}
```

In case anyone was curious; the `__construct()` interface from **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php**:

```
 /**
 * Create a new Eloquent model instance.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    $this->bootIfNotBooted();

    $this->syncOriginal();

    $this->fill($attributes);
}
```

and **Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php**:

```
 /**
 * Create a new Illuminate application instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Request $request = null)
{
    $this->registerBaseBindings($request ?: $this->createNewRequest());

    $this->registerBaseServiceProviders();

    $this->registerBaseMiddlewares();
}
```

In case these help in debugging the issue!

As per request I have included my controller element used during the post function, this is the part that seems to activate the repository and prompt the error:

```
<?php

use myapp\Repositories\Invite\InviteRepository;

class InviteController extends BaseController {

  /**
   * InviteRepository
   *
   * @var myapp\Repositories\Invite\InviteRepository
   */
  protected $repository;

  /**
   * Create a new instance of the InviteController
   *
   * @param myapp\Repositories\Invite\InviteRepository
   */
  public function __construct(InviteRepository $repository)
  {
    $this->repository = $repository;
  }

  /**
   * Create a new invite
   *
   * @return Response
   */
  public function store()
  {
    $invite = $this->repository->create(Input::all());
  }

}
```

**RepositoryServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php namespace myapp\Repositories;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

  /**
   * Register
   */
  public function register()
  {
    $this->registerInviteRepository();
  }

 /**
   * Register the Invite Repository
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function registerInviteRepository()
  {
    $this->app->bind('myapp\Repositories\Invite\InviteRepository', function($app)
    {
      return new EloquentInviteRepository( new Invite );
    });
  }
}
```

Any idea's as to what I am missing?

Thanks for the help guys,
You've been a great resource so far!

Comment: Show the code that caused the error.

Comment: @deczo Sorry for my ignorance but I'm not sure what code you want. I am going to include the controller element that is activated upon a post request, this is what is triggering the Repository and prompting the error.

Comment: @deczo `public function store()` is the direct function called on by the post function of the form.

Comment: Did you bind `EloquentInviteRepository` in the IoC container?

Comment: @deczo I'm new to this, but i believe that instead of an IoC container I have used ServiceProviders and linked those to my `app.php` file in `app/config`. Is this where I am going wrong?

Comment: Yes, service provider is the place where you bind it. Check this one, because it seems you made something wrong right there.

Comment: @deczo Do I need to register my service provider anywhere other than the app.php file? I've done that but it doesn't seem to be working, still getting the same error and I need to individually register my repositories as well?

Comment: Show your service provider. You bind your interface to the concrete implementation and that binding seems to be wrong.

Comment: @deczo ^done. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Really really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

In the file `RepositoryServiceProvider.php`, replace this

```
$this->app->bind('myapp\Repositories\Invite\InviteRepository', function($app)
{
    return new EloquentInviteRepository( new Invite );
});
```

With this:

```
$this->app->bind('myapp\Repositories\Invite\InviteRepository', 
                    'myapp\Repositories\Invite\EloquentInviteRepository');
```